# PhpStorm and Docker - Unable to configure the Remote PHP interpreter (Failed to parse script validation output)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, phpstorm, ddev

I'm using Docker composer with a PHP. When trying to set the interpreter I choose Docker compose and connecting with existing container and then it fails with the error

> Failed to parse script validation output.

If I execute `php -v` inside the container everything seems fine.

It's working fine with docker-compose run lifecycle.

PS:

- PhpStorm 2023.1.2
- Docker version 24.0.2, build cb74dfc
- Docker Compose version v2.18.1
- docker-compose version 1.24.0, build 0aa59064
- docker-py version: 3.7.2
- CPython version: 3.6.8
- OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.0j 20 Nov 2018
- `Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Docker > Tools` and checking the box "Use Compose V2" didn't work for me.

Getting below error in ide.log

```text
2023-06-15 11:30:07,860 [1825374] FINE - #c.j.p.c.p.PhpInfoUtil - Parsing validation output: Could not open input file: /opt/.phpstorm_helpers/phpinfo.php

2023-06-15 11:30:07,861 [1825375] INFO - STDERR - [Fatal Error] :1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.

2023-06-15 11:30:07,861 [1825375] WARN - #c.j.p.c.p.PhpInfoUtil - Failed to parse validation output: Could not open input file: /opt/.phpstorm_helpers/phpinfo.php

2023-06-15 11:30:07,862 [1825376] FINE - #c.j.p.c.p.PhpInfoUtil -

com.intellij.execution.ExecutionException: Failed to parse validation script output
```

[image: Error]

##### What is the expected result?

An installed php version should be shown

##### What happens instead?

Failed to parse validation script output message and PHP version: not installed label

Comment: You don't mention the DDEV version you're using, what does `ddev --version` say? I recommend using the DDEV Integration Plugin, https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/install/phpstorm/#ddev-integration-plugin and please make sure you've read through the setup instructions, https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/install/phpstorm/#phpstorm-setup

Comment: I think you might do better with this (after doing those things) by coming over to DDEV Discord for interactive help. https://discord.gg/hCZFfAMc5k - Before you arrive please do a `ddev debug test` and provide the output of that as either a gist (gist.github.com) or other pastebin, or as a file.

Comment: For reference purposes: a ticket on PhpStorm Issue Tracker with the same -- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-73058

Comment: ddev version v1.21.6
Yes I am using the DDEV integration plugin and still I am getting the same error.

Comment: I have pased the output of ddev debug test at below:

https://github.com/ddev/ddev/issues/4985

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a PhpStorm issue, mentioned in several issues there. I know you will follow up.

- https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/8402591953554--Failed-to-parse-validation-script-output-for-remote-Docker-compose-CLI-interpreter
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-46602/Failed-to-parse-validation-script-output-with-docker-compose

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to that intellij-support.jetbrains.com issue.
In my case it was a case-sensitive issue.
My project directory name had a capital in it.
The DDEV phpstorm plugin took over that capital for the COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME environment variable.
But the generated name in ./.ddev/.ddev-docker-compose-full.yaml was lowercase.
Link to my comment on the jetbrains page:
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/8402591953554/comments/15774385111442

Comment: I don't believe docker-compose allows upper-case project names.